# How to get heredoc to not escape my characters?

Tags: bash, command-line, heredoc

I am trying to pass some code to a REPL and this heredoc seems to be escaping my regex. To shorten the problem... I have a really long regex but this is the main problem:

```
<<SOMECODE
\\d
SOMECODE
```

This is returned by the heredoc as

```
\d
```

How do I get the heredoc to not remove my extra slash? I thought heredocs were immune to characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Quote Your Here-Document Delimiter

If you want to prevent most escapes and expansions, you can surround your Bash here-document delimiter with single quotes. For example:

```
cat << 'SOMECODE'
\\d
SOMECODE
```

prints `\\d` on my system.